# Kendo UI ListView that consumes object with array

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-listview

How can I get my ListView to loop through object property `timetableRecords`. I'm googling around but can't find way to do it.

**Example of data (swagger response model schema):**

```
{
  "from": {
    "name": "string"
  },
  "to": {
    "name": "string"
  },
  "price": 0,
  "date": "2016-07-25T11:52:52.674Z",
  "timetableRecords": [
    {
      "departure": "2016-07-25T11:52:52.675Z",
      "arrival": "2016-07-25T11:52:52.675Z"
    }
  ],
  "fetchedOn": "2016-07-25T11:52:52.675Z"
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="timetableRecords"></div>

<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
    <div class="timetable-record">
        <p>#:departure#</p>
        <p>#:arrival#</p>
    </div>
</script>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#timetableRecords').kendoListView({
    template: kendo.template($("#template").html()),
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'api/timetable?from=station_name1&to=station_name2',
                dataType: 'json'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So its been awhile since you posted this, but I have a solution for you (doubtful you will still need it).

The schema.parse() event can help you:

> Executed before the server response is used. Use it to preprocess or parse the server response.

Here is your updated Datasource is below:

```
dataSource: {
  transport: {
    read: {
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'api/timetable?from=station_name1&to=station_name2',
      dataType: 'json'
    }
  },
  schema:
    parse: fucntion(e) {
      return e.timetableRecords
  }
}
```

This way your DataSource is processing a list of 'timetableRecords', and your template would be valid.

Good luck,

Grant